# What licenses can access Knowledge, Reporting, and Salesforce Console in Salesforce Classic?

Tags: visualforce, licenses, console, editions

What licenses can access read-only Knowledge, a Visualforce Page, and Reporting through a Custom Salesforce Console in Salesforce Classic?

These are the ONLY features this user group needs.

My Salesforce support meeting was cancelled and https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-and-service-cloud/ does not provide details on whether or not that license can access a custom salesforce console. The employee apps starter / employee community license does not provide access to the salesforce console in salesforce classic.

What are my options?

Thanks!

Comment: What console-specific features are required?

Comment: @DavidSchach navigation tabs of the above items and the ability to add console components such as History and the Knowledge Console Component.

Comment: The Knowledge Console Component requires Cases, doesn't it? I admit that I'm not up on that, but you can display all that Knowledge stuff with a tab. A tab like you can get without using a console. If you don't need a list of records, and you don't plan to use sub-tabs, then why would you need the console? This sounds over-complicated.

Comment: @DavidSchach The Knowledge Console Component does not require cases. I understand Salesforce classic without using the console allows us to access articles through Knowledge exactly the same. 

We would like to use the console for the following:
In console tabs for quickly hopping back and forth between articles.
History Console Component to view articles recently viewed as well as in-console bookmarked articles.